# Cucumber: Are there "procedures\macros" available in cucumber feature file?

Tags: cucumber

I would like to know If I can replace duplicate parts with something like a procedure call.
For example, given the following situation:

```
@Sanity
Scenario: Scenario1
  Given....
  And....
  And....
  When....
  Then verify something
  And verify 1
  And verify 2
  And verify 3

@Sanity
Scenario: Scenario2
  Given....
  And....
  And....
  When....
  Then verify something else
  And verify 1
  And verify 2
  And verify 3
```

Can I somehow spare the duplication of the

```
  And verify 1
  And verify 2
  And verify 3
```

part by defining it as a macro or a procedure?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having multiple steps, why not have **one step** that verifies multiple things in it's step definition?

```
  And verify 1
  And verify 2
  And verify 3
```

would become

```
And verify all the things
```

The step definition for "verify all the things" would then perform each of the verifications.